Best way to ventilate small instrument case
I have a number of small cases used in a mobile audio project. Each has a 5V battery, a Raspberry P 4 and additional equipment.  The Pi is encased in an aluminium heat sink including fans and this keeps the Pi running cool while the lid of the case is open (cool being between the high 30s and low 50s, degrees C - it's a warm to hot climate here)). When the lid is closed the Pi overheats (with temperatures over 60°C) very quickly and the Pi's processor starts to stall at these temperatures.

if the hyperlink doesn't work please see: https://ibb.co/kq0Y7ct
I'm loathe to have to drill too many ventilation holes in the case for aesthetic reasons and thought that perhaps I can get away with a single ventilation hole with a fan at the top of the case (under the handle) and an air inlet somewhere near where my thumb is in the photo. 5V fans that I've seen available here online are 4x4x1cm.
This cases will not be used in the rain, so an upward facing ventilation fan should be OK.
There is space for 2 4x4cm fans under the handle. Would one such fan be sufficient or should I use two? What sort of diameter should the inlet hole(s) be?
Thanks,

You already have fans for the heat sink.
Why not have a duct to take hot air to a vent hole or a duct to bring in the cool air? A second vent hole will be needed...

Solar Mike's idea is good. Or just put one of the vent holes underneath the heat sink. Save your battery power.

Thanks, a good idea. There's probably as much heat radiating from the heat sink itself as from the fans however. This is how the case/heat-sink looks: https://postimg.cc/4nPQbp8H

@Rich 's comment is also good. I'll try with an air-vent at in the base of the suitcase, under the Pi/heat-sink. The case has a "foot" sufficiently high enough to prevent moisture entering when placed on the ground.

Looks like you may be better to have those fans blow directly out through a couple of tubes to an exterior vent as Solar Mike suggests. There's a lot of area on the heat sink that those fans don't cover.
